# Laravel 5.3 Redirect to admin page after login only if user is admin

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.3

Does anybody know simple way to make in Laravel 5.3 without extensions:

If current user is admin, then after login/registration -> make redirect to admin page. If current user is web user -> redirect to home page.

In database I put field $table->boolean('admin')->nullable();
So when user registered he is not admin by default.

Currently I did that. And I get error  `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check() in AdminMiddleware.php`

app\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->check()) {
            if (! $this->auth->user()->isAdmin() ) {
                Auth::logout();
                return redirect()->guest('/');
            } 
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
];
```

app\Http\Controllers\AdminController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {        $this->middleware('auth');    }

    public function index()
    {        return view('admin.dashboard');    }

    public function registered()
    {        return view('admin.registered');    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

After login you do it as:

```
if(auth()->user()->admin) {
    // redirect to admin page
} else {
    // redirect to home page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can use this as you app\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware.php. 
it will check if the user is logged in first and then if the user is an Admin.

The reason why you were getting that error was probably because you included *Auth* the wrong way.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Auth;

class AdminMiddleware 
{


    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        /**
         * Checks if user is Admin
        */
        if(!$this->CheckAdmin()){

            //redirect to admin login
            return redirect('/admin/login');

        }

        /**
         * Prodceed to next request
        */
        return $next($request);

    }

    /**
     * Checks if user is logged in as an admin
     */
    private function CheckAdmin(){

        /**
         * Check If User Is Logged In
        */
        if (!Auth::check()) {

            return false;

        }

        /**
         * Check If User has administrator role
        */
        if (!Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {

            return false;

        }

        //passed Admin rules
        return true;

    }


}
```

Don't forget to use the 'admin' middleware in your controller. It seems that you are using the standard 'auth' middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses `RedirectUsers::redirectPath()` to get redirect path.

It only checks a property `redirectTo`.

If you want apply custom logic - just overwrite `redirectPath()` method in your controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    // protected $redirectTo = '/';
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        // ...
        // custom logic here 
        // ...

        // return desired URL
        return '/my/custom/url/here';
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

}
```

The same approach will work for `RegisterController` and `ResetPasswordController`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:-

1) Create a new table in phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `role_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `role_description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT

ALTER TABLE `role`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `role`
--
ALTER TABLE `role`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

2) Add a foreign key in user table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_role` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('0','1','2') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT;
```

3) Add below code in user model i.e user.php App/User.php

```
/**
     * Description : check user role which type of users login
     */ 
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'id', 'user_role');
    }
    /**
     * Description : check has role if user has any role assigned
     */ 
    public function hasRole($roles)
    {
        //die('inside hasRole');

        $this->have_role = $this->getUserRole();

        // Check if the user is a root account
        if($this->have_role->role_name == 'Admin') {
            return true;
        }

        if(is_array($roles)){
            foreach($roles as $need_role){
                if($this->checkIfUserHasRole($need_role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else{
            return $this->checkIfUserHasRole($roles);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Description : check role from database
     */ 
    private function getUserRole()
    {
        return $this->role()->getResults();
    }

    // 
    private function checkIfUserHasRole($need_role)
    {
        return (strtolower($need_role)==strtolower($this->have_role->role_name)) ? true : false;
    }
```

4) Create a new file inside \app\Http\Middleware with name of CheckRole.php add below code in this file

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

// First copy this file into your middleware directory

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CheckRole{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Get the required roles from the route
        $roles = $this->getRequiredRoleForRoute($request->route());

        // Check if a role is required for the route, and
        // if so, ensure that the user has that role.
        if($request->user()->hasRole($roles) || !$roles)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('admin/logout');
        /*return response([

            'error' => [
                'code' => 'INSUFFICIENT_ROLE',
                'description' => 'You are not authorized to access this resource.'
            ]
        ], 401);*/

    }

    private function getRequiredRoleForRoute($route)
    {
        $actions = $route->getAction();
        return isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;
    }

}
```

5) Replace the below code in \app\Http\Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

With below code

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        'CheckRole' => [
            'web',
            'auth',
            'roles'
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

And

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
```

With below code

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'roles'     => 'App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole',
    ];
```

6) most important point your rout file \routes\web.php should be something like below controller may be vary based on your requirements

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');



Route::group(['middleware' => ['CheckRole'], 'roles' => ['admin']], function () {
    //Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@index');
    //Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['CheckRole'], 'roles' => ['employee']], function () {
    //Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/employee', 'EmployeeController@index');

});
```